# Good tools for reverse engineering colaboratively?

Tags: web-application, malware, opensource, reverse-engineering

Does anybody know a good set of tools for doing reverse engineering of binaries in a collaborative way?. My original idea is to disassemble a binary, allowing to add information about functions, parameters, global variables, etc. Then such information should be propagated in all the analyzed modules.

It should be an open source platform. A good (but closed) example of this is [CrowdRE alpha](http://blog.crowdstrike.com/2012/06/join-crowd.html)

At least, i will need some kind of version control system (svn, git, etc) and a disassembler (like [radare2](http://www.radare.org)).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The only experience I have with collaborative reverse engineering is using the collabREate plugin with IDA Pro. You can check it out [here](http://www.idabook.com/collabreate/).

Although I don't have any personal experience with many of these, it is probably also worth checking out the [collaborative RCE tool library](http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/Category%3aRCE_Tools), which lists many options for collaborative debugging.

Comment: Another example, but still based on IDA: https://github.com/zynamics/bincrowd-plugin-ida